# Are Apollo Client's data properties always guaranteed to be objects?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Apollo docs state,

> data: TData
>
> An object containing the result of your GraphQL query. Defaults to an empty object.

Give that it "defaults to an empty object", does that mean I can depend on `data` passed by Query to never being `null`, `undefined` or any non-object data type? If yes, does that same hold true for `data` pass by Mutations.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#render-prop